# Using Mutual SSL with HttpRIO

Tags: delphi

If anybody know how to use Mutual SSL with HttpRIO (SOAP). I'm using Delphi 10.3.2 
Also certificate key is stored on PKI card but this is not problem.

I tried many things but don't have any idea how to do it :(
Any advice or code is welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will self answer my question because I found solution and this can be also useful for someone else.

- To provide client certificate simply use event:

```
HTTPWebNode.OnNeedClientCertificate
```

then you simply select certificate with passed argument *TCertificateList*.

- To approve server certificate use event:

```
HTTPWebNode.HTTP.OnValidateServerCertificate
```